# "Verbose" auto in Coq

Tags: coq, verbose

I'm learning Coq and the book I'm learning from, ([CPDT](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/toc.html)) makes heavy use of `auto` in proofs.

Since I'm learning I think it might be helpful for me to see exactly what `auto` is doing under the hood (the less magic early on the better). Is there any way to force it to display exactly what tactics or techniques it's using to compute the proof?

If not, is there a place which details exactly what `auto` does?

Answer (score 21):

There are multiple ways to get a glance at what is going on under the hood.

TLDR: Put `info` before your tactic, or use `Show Proof.` before and after calling the tactic and spot the differences.

---

To see what a particular tactic invocation has been doing, you can prefix is with `info`, so as to show the particular proof steps it has taken.

(This might be broken with Coq 8.4, I see that they provide `info_` versions of some tactics, read the error message if you need to.)

This is probably what you want at a beginner level, it can already be quite terse.

---

Another way to see what is currently going on within a proof is to use the command `Show Proof.`. It will show you the currently built term with holes, and show you which hole each of your current goals is supposed to fill.

This is probably more advanced, especially if you use tactic such as `induction` or `inversion`, as the term being built is going to be fairly involved, and will require you to understand the underlying nature of induction schemes or dependent pattern-matching (which CPDT should teach you soon enough).

---

Once you have finished a proof with `Qed.` (or `Defined.`), you can also ask to look at the term that was built by using `Print term.` where `term` is the name of the theorem/term.

This will often be a big and ugly term, and it needs some training to be able to read these for involved terms. In particular, if the term has been built via the use of powerful tactics (such as `omega`, `crush`, etc.), it is probably going to be unreadable. You'd basically only use that to scan at some particular place of the term you're interested in. If it's more than 10 lines long, don't even bother reading it in such a crude format! :)

---

With all of the previous, you can use `Set Printing All.` beforehand, so that Coq prints the unfolded, explicit versions of everything. It is additionally verbose but can help when you wonder what the values of implicit parameters are.

These are all the ones I can think of on the top of my head, there might be more though.

---

As for what a tactic does, the usual best answer is found in the documentation:

http://coq.inria.fr/distrib/V8.4/refman/Reference-Manual011.html#@tactic155

Basically, `auto` tries to use all the hints provided (depending on the database you use), and to solve your goal combining them up to some depth (that you can specify). By default, the database is `core` and the depth is `5`.

More info on that can be found here:

http://coq.inria.fr/distrib/V8.4/refman/Reference-Manual011.html#Hints-databases

Comment: `info_auto` shows only the "path to success". To see what exactly `auto` tries one can use `debug auto.`: it shows all the fails (!) and successes.